# Hamachi behind a corporate firewall blocking my hamachi

Tags: vpn, hamachi

I have hamachi in two locations outside my work and one inside my work.

The locations outside of work can contact each other fine and can contact the work machines fine, but the work machine can not contact either of the other locations?  I have both windows and ubuntu 9.04 at work and it doesn't work on either.

I would think it was config if I couldn't contact the work machines from home.

What can I do to get hamachi working from my office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used hamachi until now, but I think that if it's based on a TCP or UDP connection, you simply have to change the "listening port" on the home machine to something like 80 or 443, so the corporate firewall will think it's a legitimate connection.

(I think that the corporate firewall doesn't do deep packet inspection, so that you really can't do that)

Later edit:
 You can also try encapsulation of the hamachi traffic over an ssh tunnel, so you have to connect hamachi

Read this tutorial: http://www.ytechie.com/2008/05/set-up-a-windows-ssh-tunnel-in-10-minutes-or-less.html

Answer (score 3):

Ask the network admin to unblock the required ports in the corporate firewall. Other solutions will probably infringe some usage rules you singned.

Comment: And if the admin doesn't want to open up the ports, it's probably because that admin has no control over the security of any computer at home (and cannot tell if the Hamachi closed source code and protocol are secure). So, connecting the office network to home networks might introduce serious risks.